# how to remove the " \ " sign in the input in golang raw json

Tags: json, go, escaping

and this is an example of its input

```
[
    {
        \"type\":\"Non Custom\",
        \"so_no\":\"3250109150\",
        \"material_code\":\"F100101180028\",
        \"po_no\":\"JDC/00067/02/22/2/DL\",
        \"pr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_date\":\"\"
    },
    {
        \"type\":\"Non Custom\",
        \"so_no\":\"3250109150\",
        \"material_code\":\"F100101180030\",
        \"po_no\":\"JDC/00067/02/22/2/DL\",
        \"pr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_date\":\"\"
    }
]
```

Remove the \ sign in raw json input

*And please help who can fix it*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To stand a better chance of getting a useful answer to your question, please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Raw json does not contain backslashes the way you show. It's likely that these backslashes are not really there but are just an artefact of how you're printing/showing the json. Please describe **how** you got to the json-with-backslashes that you posted

Comment: because it's input from RPA (automatic process robot)

Comment: and later the input from the robot will be processed and stored in the database, with a note that the \ sign must be removed first

Comment: This is not a valid JSON document, and there's no such thing as "raw JSON". So, you should somehow rephrase your problem in a way it's clear you have certain junk, and you want to (supposedly) obtain a regular JSON document out of it. With such statement, you should "unescape" the double quoted-strings, but you should watch out for other possible usage of the backslash: I mean, if the generator which produced this junk would need to "encode" `"Non\nCustom"`, would it produce `\"Non\\nCustom\"`? I mean, you should first clearly understand the rules of this garbage encoding.

Comment: To make my comment more clear: as it's not a valid JSON document, you cannot really ask how to "parse this JSON" because your data is not in that format. So you have to "decode" it first _to_ a valid JSON document, and then apply the usual `encoding/json` calls to decode _that._

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can pass the JSON into a string and replace every backslash like shown below:

```
json := `[
    {
        \"type\":\"Non Custom\",
        \"so_no\":\"3250109150\",
        \"material_code\":\"F100101180028\",
        \"po_no\":\"JDC/00067/02/22/2/DL\",
        \"pr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_date\":\"\"
    },
    {
        \"type\":\"Non Custom\",
        \"so_no\":\"3250109150\",
        \"material_code\":\"F100101180030\",
        \"po_no\":\"JDC/00067/02/22/2/DL\",
        \"pr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_no\":\"\",
        \"gr_date\":\"\"
    }
]`
fmt.Println(strings.ReplaceAll(json, "\\", ""))
```

Comment: Of course if there are any escape sequences in the underlying JSON, this will break it.